# Java Swing Arabic text reversed direction

Tags: java, swing, arabic, right-to-left

I had a correctly working/displaying Java Swing app that manipulated text IO in Arabic. Suddenly today, I find every Arabic text word displayed in reverse direction on my MacBook Pro with a Java8u171. To verify it's not something wrong with my programs, I recreated the app on the [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/bidi.html#setting-component-orientation) page and ran it on my laptop. To my surprise, I am getting the same reversed display! Namely, instead of getting this correct image shown below (extracted from the referenced tutorial page):
[image]

I am getting this one instead when I build the app as is and run on my laptop:

[image]

Could anybody shed light on what happened here please? Thank you.

Comment: Can you share a bit of your code? The part where you set the orientation.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/examples/InternationalizedMortgageCalculator.java

Comment: Can you paste here one of your arabic labels' text?

Comment: Sure, something like "Monthly Payment", or
الدفع الشهري

Comment: I can confirm everything works fine on Windows, with minor release 181

Comment: Try with the latest 8.* release, if it happens, open a bug report on the OpenJDK bug system or via the Oracle page https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/

Comment: Thank you so much for your verification! Indeed it may just be a bug in the u171 release. Will adjust, try different releases and report back.

Comment: Nope! Just tried with Java8u201 - the latest - but same bad reversed effect. From your test also, only MacOS platforms are affected. Not worth filing the bug I need to solve my problem quicker. I had filed several bugs with them before and they took ages to even recognize I had issues without solving it.

Comment: Have you noticed if this is valid only for labels, or for every other component?

Comment: Anything Arabic is all garbled, but, updating to Java 11 (or anything past 8 really) could be a fix. Thanks for your pointing about Java releases.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Windows based computer, you're probably fine according to the comments in the original post. For your Mac OS'ers, you need to step away from Java 8 entirely and into Java 11 (or newer going forward). Testing with that gives the desired look shown below. I tested this with my own apps on JTextPane and all those input text components, we're back in business :-)

[image]

Comment: The app works from within the NetBeans IDE. However, when I generate the executable JAR, the reversed display is back again :-( Something the Netbeans environment provides that's missing in the JAR file.

Comment: That is really strange. I'll try on Linux tomorrow morning, just out of curiosity